# Angular + amazon-cognito-identity-js, why am I getting error: global is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-cognito

From a command line:

```
ng new sandbox
cd .\sandbox\
ng serve
```

Open http://localhost:4200/. It works.

```
npm install --save amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

Inside `\src\app\sign-up\sign-up.component.ts` add this line of code:

```
import * as AmazonCognitoIdentity from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

Add a constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool({});
  }
```

Refresh http://localhost:4200/.

Page is blank. There is a console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/AuthenticationHelper.js (AuthenticationHelper.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/es/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:94)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
```

What is the best way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Put this as the last line in `/src/polyfills.ts`

```
(window as any).global = window
```

Comment: thank you very much! this did it for me! :) may we know what's the issue and how this line solves it? thanks :D

Comment: @Mon did you ever figure out why this line works?

Comment: nope, sadly. also haven't done any frontend lately. hopefully @danday74 can answer?

Comment: I have this error too using Quasar framework.

Answer (score 2):

I had been looking at the issue and I was able to fixed following this link: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/678#issuecomment-384260863

> if (global === undefined) {
>     var global = window;   }

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is reading this and is using Angular >15 (cf: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfills), Since polyfills.ts doesn't exist anymore in the default angular project, you can create your naming it as you want and place it under the folder you wish to (ex: src/crossbrowsers/my-custom-polyfills.ts)

Then add it in:

1. Angular.json file
   in "polyfills" arrays (under project/smart/architect/build/options/polyfills and project/smart/architect/test/options/polyfills [for tests] )

you will have something like:

project/smart/architect/build/options/polyfills

```
"options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/smart",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "src/crossbrowsers/my-custom-polyfills.ts"
            ],
          ...
          } ...
```

project/smart/architect/test/options/polyfills

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js",
          "zone.js/testing",
          "src/crossbrowsers/my-custom-polyfills.ts"
        ],
        ...
       } ...
```

2. tsconfig.app.json file

in files array.
You will have something like:

```
...
"files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/crossbrowsers/my-custom-polyfills.ts"
  ],
...
```