# Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, aws-sdk, node-modules

My project was working fine until i install aws-sdk (link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk ) .

I tried google.. but not able to solve this issue..

I'm getting this error :

`core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined
ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/buffer/index.js (index.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHashUtils.js (browserHashUtils.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserHmac.js (browserHmac.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browserCryptoLib.js (browserCryptoLib.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/browser_loader.js (browser_loader.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)`

Comment: pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58628335/6236935

Comment: got answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175544/angular-amazon-cognito-identity-js-why-am-i-getting-error-global-is-not-defi it can help others..
thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update **/src/polyfills.ts** by adding:

```
// aws-sdk requires global to exist
(window as any).global = window;
```